# When getting a list of properties (via reflection) can we exclude the ReadOnly ones?

Tags: .net, reflection

This code will get us all the properties of a class:

```vb
Dim myPropertyInfo As PropertyInfo()
     = myType.GetProperties((BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance))
```

or in C#:

```cs
PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo
     = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);
```

But is there a way to get just the properties defined as ReadOnly?

Or, equally, to exclude the ReadOnly properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just filter the results to those which have `CanWrite` as `False`

```
Dim items As PropertyInfo() = Me. _
  GetType(). _
  GetProperties(Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public). _
  Where(Function(x) Not x.CanWrite). _
  ToArray() _
```

Note the above code sample is assuming `Visual Studio 2008` or higher and requires an import of `System.Linq`.  If you're using an older version you can do the following

```
Dim props As PropertyInfo() = Me.GetType().GetProperties(Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
Dim readOnlyProps As New List(Of PropertyInfo)
For Each cur in props 
  If Not cur.CanWrite Then
    readOnlyProps.Add(cur)
  End If
Next
```